# Autocomplete to show all options on focus. How?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-plugins

I'm using [jQuery UI autocomplete](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

How do I show all the options available in the dropdown for an input field when it receives focus? Right now, I have to type something for the plugin to filter the options.

What I have right now

```
var $sessionTimes = "00:00 00:15 00:30 00:45 1:00 1:15".split(" ");
$(".autocompleteTime").autocomplete($sessionTimes);

<input type="text" class="autocompleteTime" size="5" />
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to set minChars to be 0, like this:

```
$('.autocompleteTime').autocomplete($sessionTimes, {minChars: 0});
```

Also note that you don't have to start variable name with a $, you could just write sessionTimes everywhere you use it and it would be okay. Probably coming from a PHP background? :)

Comment: Thanks inkredibl. That works. Well, i like dollars more the better :)

Comment: I tried this but you still need to press down arrow or click the control to actually show the autocomplete options.

Comment: Maybe from a Perl background ?

Comment: @Fajar What do you mean? Of course the user has to trigger it. If you want it to trigger automatically just call `click()` on it, i.e. `$('.autocompleteTime').click()`

Comment: FYI, this is called "minLength" in recent versions of the plugin.

Comment: @alex I think what @Fajar meant was that it doesn't trigger on initial focus - when the user first clicks into the autocomplete textbox he doesn't get the dropdown. He'd have to still type a character or press the up arrow to get suggestions.

Comment: Awesome! I needed to do what @Fajar wanted to do. `$('.autocompleteTime').click(function(e){ $('#' + e.target.id).keydown() });` for this example would do the trick. And, @notJim's correction was right.

Answer (score 11):

This is the correct answer:

```
    $('.autocompleteTime').autocomplete($sessionTimes, {minChars: 0})
    .focus(function () {
        $(this).autocomplete('search', $(this).val())
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

The selected answer is a bit old and didn't really work for me, so what worked for me was this:

```
$('#selector')
    //use minLength when initializing so that empty searches work
    .autocomplete({..., minLength: 0})
    //trigger the search on focus
    .focus(function(){
        $(this).autocomplete('search', $(this).val());
    })
```

Credits to the comment by  @notJim above and this question: [Display jquery ui auto-complete list on focus event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132058/display-jquery-ui-auto-complete-list-on-focus-event), and to me

Answer (score 2):

Check out jQuery Ui's Autocomplete combobox example:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: Problem with this is it does not allow input without choosing a selection

Answer (score 0):

That module has now been incorporated into the jQuery UI.  This post covers how to deal with this problem now:

[Jquery UI autocomplete; minLength:0 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604216/jquery-ui-autocomplete-minlength0-issue)