# Display jquery ui auto-complete list on focus event

Tags: jquery

here is my code, anything wrong with it ?
it doesn't seem to display list on focus, i still have to press a key before it displays list

```
<link media="all" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#id').autocomplete({
            source: ["ActionScript",
                        "AppleScript",
                        "Asp",
                        "BASIC",
                        "C",
                        "C++",
                        "Clojure",
                        "COBOL",
                        "ColdFusion",
                        "Erlang",
                        "Fortran",
                        "Groovy",
                        "Haskell",
                        "Java",
                        "JavaScript",
                        "Lisp",
                        "Perl",
                        "PHP",
                        "Python",
                        "Ruby",
                        "Scala",
                        "Scheme"
                    ],
            minLength: 0
        });
    }).focus(function(){            
            $(this).trigger('keydown.autocomplete');
    });
</script>


<input type="text" id="id">
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Looks like you are attaching your `focus()` handler to the anonymous function and not the text box.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#id').autocomplete({
            source: ["ActionScript",
                        /* ... */
                    ],
            minLength: 0
        }).focus(function(){            
            // The following works only once.
            // $(this).trigger('keydown.autocomplete');
            // As suggested by digitalPBK, works multiple times
            // $(this).data("autocomplete").search($(this).val());
            // As noted by Jonny in his answer, with newer versions use uiAutocomplete
            $(this).data("uiAutocomplete").search($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why the down-rate with no comment? What was it for?

Comment: Anyone ever figure out how to make this work more than once?  I just realized I posted a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206603/how-to-make-jquery-autocomplete-list-display-all-options-onfocus-and-hide-after

Comment: This displays the pulldown twice

Comment: this works only for first time, but if you replace keydown with search it works every time. i.e.:  `$(this).autocomplete("search", "");`

Comment: @AhmadNadeem Thank you, I was looking for the more modern equivalent. All the solutions here are broken in the latest versions of jQuery UI.

Comment: @AhmadNadeem - just used this and it worked for me with a space between quotes in the second argument: `$(this).autocomplete("search"," ");` The solution as it appears in the answer doesn't work in 1.12.1

Answer (score 98):

This directly call search method with default value when focus.

http://jsfiddle.net/steelywing/ubugC/

```
$("input").autocomplete({
    source: ["Apple", "Boy", "Cat"],
    minLength: 0,
}).focus(function () {
    $(this).autocomplete("search");
});
```

Comment: The chosen solution no longer works (if it ever worked at all). The [jQuery UI](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search) method "search" is the best way to manually trigger the element to display its search results. This answer works.

Comment: Use $(this).autocomplete("search", "") if you want to show all items on focus even when the already input contains some text.

Comment: True, best answer. Thanks @steely Wing

Comment: Short and simple. Best answer!

Comment: For anyone trying to get it work quickly, don't forget to specify the **minLength** to **0**. Works like a charm ;)

Comment: Anyone knows a solution to make it work with autofocus set to true ? Rendering the JS code before the input does not seem to help

Comment: This no longer works but the accepted answer works perfectly !

Answer (score 61):

The solution to make it work more than once

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#id').autocomplete({
            source: ["ActionScript",
                        /* ... */
                    ],
            minLength: 0
        }).focus(function(){     
            //Use the below line instead of triggering keydown
            $(this).data("autocomplete").search($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Testing with jQuery UI 1.10.0 you need to use `.data("uiAutocomplete")` instead of `.data("autocomplete")`

Comment: `$(this).autocomplete("search")` is suggested in the [API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search)

Comment: mine is jquery ui 1.9.1 and it already uses data("uiAutocomplete") instead of data("autocomplete"). please correct that on the code.

Comment: This is awesome i give you up vote  but what if we use catcomplete with widget? It is not working more than once for catcomplete.

Comment: This is a better answer than the previous one here. At least for me... Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

digitalPBK almost has it right...

His solution works more than once but doesn't close the drop list when you select an item from the list with a mouse-click. In that case, the focus goes back to the control when you do the click, so it re-opens the list when it should be closing it.

Here's a fix, and it's the only that works for me the way I think it should work when using the latest version right now (1.8.11) of the autocomplete() function. When the control receives the focus, it doesn't do the display-all-on-focus if the drop-list is already shown...

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() {
        $('#id').autocomplete({
            source: ["ActionScript",
                        /* ... */
                    ],
            minLength: 0
        }).focus(function () {
            if ($(this).autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
                return;
            }
            $(this).data("autocomplete").search($(this).val());
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks!This is IMHO way the best solution to the issue.

Comment: Excellent Answer! Focus event will be called multiple times and if data is huge browser will freeze. We need If condition

Answer (score 9):

`$(this).trigger('keydown.autocomplete');` doesn't quite work for me.

This is what I did:

```
$('#id').on( "focus", function( event, ui ) {
    $(this).trigger(jQuery.Event("keydown"));
   // Since I know keydown opens the menu, might as well fire a keydown event to the element
});
```

Answer (score 6):

With more recent versions you might need to change autocomplete to uiAutocomplete

```
$(this).data("uiAutocomplete").search($(this).val());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change something about jQuery UI, do it jQuery UI way.

Utilize jQuery UI [Widget Factory](https://api.jqueryui.com/jquery.widget/). It's easier to maintain, faster, and much cleaner than attaching events to element.

```
$.widget('custom.autocomplete', $.ui.autocomplete, {
  options: {
    minLength: 0
  },
  _create: function() {
    this._on(this.element, {
      focus: function(event) {
        this.search();
      }
    });

    this._super();
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The generic purpose of AutoComplete is to execute on key press and based on the Letter we type it will perform often a wild-card search and show the result.

Anyway, from the code above i can see that :

focus(function(){
        $(this).trigger('keydown.autocomplete');

which is attached as told by Codesleuth, to the anonymous function instead of the Control.

Answer (score -1):

This working right way.

```
$.widget('custom.autocomplete', $.ui.autocomplete, {
  options: {
    minLength: 0
  },
  _create: function() {
    this._on(this.element, {
      focus: function(event) {
        this.search();
      }
    });

    this._super();
  }
});
```