# How to show all items on click of autocompleteextender target search textbox?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, dom-events, autocompleteextender

I am trying to display all the list items on an autocompleteextender in asp.net. I have set the MinimumPrefixLength = 0 as suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681877/auto-populate-autocompleteextender-with-all-possibilities-on-first-click). My problem is that the list doesn't show on first click. Only if I type something and remove it and then click on it, it shows the list. How do achieve it in the first click?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I couldn't get the desired result after trying a lot. Hence decided to go with jquery select2 plugin for normal dropdowncontrols.