# Jquery UI autocomplete; minLength:0 issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using a JQuery UI auto-complete. I am specifying the min length. If I specify `minLength:2` I need to type 2 characters before the service fires. If I specify `minLength:1` then I only need to type one character before the source service fires.

However, when I specify `minLength:0` I still need to type one character. So whats the point of `0`? how is it any different than `1`? The expected, and desired, behavior would be for it to fire as soon as the input has focus...?

Ideas?

**Update:** For the most part karim's solution below works, however when clicking on the input the options come up and when one is clicked the source is resubmitted the *empty string* rather than the *new option* that was just selected, so the auto-complete options that come up after selecting an option are than *same as if the box had been empty*.

Comment: What is the expected behavior anyways when you have `minLength:0`?

Comment: Basically, you want all available results to pop up when you focus on the autocomplete field?

Comment: Well, not exactly, but yes. Did I confuse you? I want all results the service returns to pop up. However, this may or may not be all possible results. For instance if my service ranks all remaining possible results and displays only the top ten, It would not display all possible results, but, yes the auto complete would display all results returned to it by the web service... I hope that made sense... :)

Comment: If you leave off the second parameter to the `search` invocation, it will use the value from the field (i.e. do not include the empty string): `.focus(function() {$(this).autocomplete("search");});`  (jQuery's documentation on this operation seems to imply the empty string works, but specifying no parameter works instead)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Check out the [`search`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#method-search) method documentation:

> Triggers a search event, which, when
>   data is available, then will display
>   the suggestions; can be used by a
>   selectbox-like button to open the
>   suggestions when clicked. If no value
>   argument is specified, the current
>   input's value is used. **Can be called
>   with an empty string and minLength: 0
>   to display all items.**

```js
var source = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'];

var firstVal = source[0];

$("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: source,
}).focus(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete("search", $(this).val());
});
```

```css
.ui-menu-item{
  background : rgb(215, 215, 215);;  
  border : 1px solid white;
  list-style-type: none;
  cursor : pointer;
}

.ui-menu-item:hover{
  background : rgb(200, 200, 200);
}


.ui-autocomplete{
   padding-left:0;
   margin-top  : 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id="autocomplete"/>&nbsp;<input id="submit" type="submit"/>
```

Comment: so something like $("#myAC").onFocus("search","")? - EDIT: I guess your edit answers this question :) Thanks!

Comment: @kralco626 - just chain a `.focus` handler to the autocomplete initialisation, as in the above example and demo.

Comment: @karim - do you have any idea why this is not implemented automatically when  `minLength:0`? What other meaning than this can setting `mineLength:0` possibly mean? I mean, what else could the programmer want to happen that Jquery would not implement this by default?

Comment: @kralco626 - I'm really not sure. It would *seem* like the only purpose of `minlength: 0` would be to use it in conjunction with the search method, so it is surprising that `minlength: 0` does not do that automatically.

Comment: @karim - I suppose that having `minLength:0` would call the source when you type a single character and then click backspace, whereas `minLength:1` would not... Just seems like that's really not all that great. If your going to call the source when you type a character and then backspace, why cant you call it when it gains focus? Its going to be the same call either way...

Comment: @karmin - the only issue that I have is that when you click on one of the auto-complete options, it regains focus, which means that it opens the search thing again. suppose I could just have a `if(length of text in search box <= 0)` in the focus handler... that should do it...

Comment: I guess the search won't fire onfocus to prevent searching default values like: "Search here"... [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/rbVd4/)

Comment: Hum, but generally arn't watermarks like that usually removed when the user clicks the input? At least mine are. As long as the function to remove the watermark runs before the function to do the auto-complete... idk... but ya that makes sense.

Comment: @karim - OK i'm having an issue. When I click an option from the auto-complete, it opens back-up but is resubmitting the empty string to the source rather than the new selected string.

Comment: @kralco626 - edited my answer. Maybe call the search method only if there is actually something in the input field?

Comment: @kralco626 - hang on, I don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: @karmin - i'm thinking that maybe it's not an issue with this code; it might have something to do with the code to call the service and return it to the auto-complete. I think I fixed it, however it's now errering out if I don't return any data from the service.

Comment: @karmin - sorry, the underlying problem was not with your code. It was with my service, which was causing an issue when I did not return anything to the auto-complete. I fixed it and now your solution work beautifully :)

Comment: @karmin - i'm not sure why, but adding in the `if` statement actually **causes** the problem of the auto-complete opening up the results for the empty string again after selecting an option. Doesn't make any sense to me, but without the if it works perfect. With the if, if I click on the input box and select an option, the auto-complete puts the option i selected in the input box. but then shows be the options again as if the input was empty.

Comment: @kralco626 - reverted to the previous edit. Glad I could help :)

Comment: I was looking for this exact solution. Thanks Karim!

Comment: This open on focus doesn't work well in IE. When I select item from autocomplete list, list doesn't hide itself.
You have to use rasx's answer (disable-blur-enable).

Comment: It shows all the options upon type somethig, focusout and focusin again. You should probably update it to: `$(this).autocomplete("search", this.value);`

Answer (score 7):

I understand through experiment why the accepted answer (I up-voted) can be considered slightly incomplete. I've added a little bit of intent to make the UX more combo-box-like:

```
$('#Carrier').autocomplete(
{
    source: '@Url.Action("AutocompleteCarrier", "Client")',
    minLength: 0,
    select: function (event, data) {
        $(this).autocomplete('disable');
    }
})
.blur(function(){
    $(this).autocomplete('enable');
})
.focus(function () {
    $(this).autocomplete('search', '');
});
```

Comment: Yes, this is must-have solution for Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and solved it this way.  I think the code below makes it much clearer what is the text that is sent to the autocompletion service when the field gets focus.  In particular, it is clear why it works when the field already contains something.

```
$(function() {
$("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: "completion.html",
        minLength: 0,
        select: function( event, ui ) {}
    });
});
$("input#autocomplete").focus(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete("search", $(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I got how to workaround this issue.

The problem is that when an option has been selected the input will be focused, this will run `search` without any filter and will show the `autocomplete` again.
This problem doesn't happen when you select by keyboard because the `input` is already in focus, so the code which is inside `focus` will not run again.
So to workaround this issue we have to know when the focus is triggered by any mouse/keyboar event.

```
jQuery("input#autocomplete").focus(function(e) {
    if(!e.isTrigger) {
        jQuery(this).autocomplete("search", "");
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

`e.isTrigger` is used by `jQuery` to identify when `event` has been triggered automatically or by user.

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/SdLaP/)

Answer (score 1):

This actually works! Tested on IE, FireFox

```
$("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
minLength: 0,
source: source,
}).focus(function() {
        setTimeout( "if ($('#input#autocomplete').val().length == 0) $('#input#autocomplete').autocomplete(\"search\", \"\"); ",1);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

the suggestion menu shows up for the second time because clicking on an item in suggestion menu causes text box to regain focus, however the text value is not updated when the focus is fired again.After the textbox regains focus, the suggestion menu is fired.

I dont know how we could fix this, but let me know if anyone of you are facing the similar problem

Comment: rasx' answer does the job well

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a very old thread, but I am having the exact same problem, and none of the solutions provided above seem to work... I assume that this is because of updates in Jquery? If someone could post a working updated (i.e. jquery-1.12.4.js // 1.12.1/jquery-ui.js) example, that would be fantastic.