# Jquery mobile AutoComplete not working?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I just cant seem to get this to fire, im using Jquery mobile and Asp.net mvc

inside my shared file

```
<script>
            $(function () {
            $( "#ClientName" ).autocomplete({
                minLength: 0,
                source: "@Url.Action("Search","Client")",
                focus: function( event, ui ) {
                    $("#ClientName").val(ui.item.Name);
                    return false;
                },
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    $("#ClientName").val(ui.item.Name);

                    return false;
                }
            })
                .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                    return $("<li>")
                        .data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
                        .append("<a>" + item.Name + "</a>")
                        .appendTo(ul);
                };
            });
        </script>
```

then on my mvc page

```
  <input name="ClientName" type="text" value="@Model.Name" id="ClientName" class="lightBlueStyleTextbox" placeholder="Type to search"/>
```

Comment: As a side note, you should use [JavaScriptStringEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.javascriptstringencode.aspx) for javascript generation. I.e. `source: @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Url.Action("Search","Client"), true))`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using minLength:0 it appears you are trying to create a combo-box like autocomplete. Take a look at this:
[Jquery UI autocomplete; minLength:0 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604216/jquery-ui-autocomplete-minlength0-issue)

Have you taken a look at the built in autocomplete widget in jQuery Mobile 1.3? No need to use jQuery UI maybe? http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/autocomplete/autocomplete-remote.php

Answer (score 0):

The source details should come in the json format of label and value