# jqueryui autocomplete to show available datas before start typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

The default behavior of the jqueryui autocomplete is the input field to be empty and to start listing data when the user starts typing(Even the minLength is set to 0). I want all the data to be listed as a dropdown in the beginning so the user can see all the available options. Is that possible

js file

```
$("#unique_code").autocomplete({
    source : "php/autocomplete_getunique_code.php",
    minLength: 0,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
    }
});
```

Im echoing all available data in autocomplete_getunique_code.php, but it works after start typing only. how can i achieve it, that show all available result when focusing

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery UI autocomplete; minLength:0 issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604216/jquery-ui-autocomplete-minlength0-issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try manually firing a search onFocus

```
$("#unique_code").autocomplete({
    source : "php/autocomplete_getunique_code.php",
    minLength: 0
}).focus(function(){ 
    $(this).data("autocomplete").search($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Its working superb, but the active value is not replacing i think.

Comment: When yo click on an element?

Comment: no, its replace in input box, but with using select function 
select: function( event, ui ) {
    }
$( "#unique_code" ).on( "autocompleteselect", function( event, ui ) {
    var unique_code = $("#unique_code").val();
    alert(unique_code);

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `minChars:0`?

```
   $("#unique_code").autocomplete({
        source : "php/autocomplete_getunique_code.php",
        { minChars: 0 }
    });
```