# Set jQuery Autocomplete on Textbox KeyDown Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I want jQuery Autocomplete on textbox key down event

I have tried below code, but it is not working.

```
$("#txtName").keyDown({
    $("#txtName").autocomplete({
        source: '@Url.Action("GetAllName", "Home")',
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#txtName").val(ui.item.value);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i think `$("#txtName").autocomplete()` is sufficient no need for keyDown

Comment: What does the MVC action look like?

Comment: You just want it to begin searching on the first keystroke? Try using `minLength: 1`.

Comment: @SandipPingle $("#txtName").autocomplete() is working.
But i want functionality like, when i first click on textbox and press key down, then all the results should come

Comment: @AshleyMedway Here i am using Url.Action. so Home is my controller and GetAllName is ActionName

Comment: @DevlshOne Can you please show me example.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need the `keyDown` event otherwise you are rebinding the autocomplete on every keydown.

```
$("#txtName").autocomplete({
    source: '@Url.Action("GetAllName", "Home")',
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#txtName").val(ui.item.value);
        return false;
    }
});
```

To show all results when one character is entered add `minLength: 1`

If what you want is to have all the items displayed when the textbox has focus then this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4604300/1398425

Comment: i have gone through code in given url. and that was what i wanted to do.
Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want it to begin searching on the first keystroke, try using `minLength: 1`:

```
$("#txtName").autocomplete({
    source: '@Url.Action("GetAllName", "Home")',
    minLength: 1,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#txtName").val(ui.item.value);
        return false;
    }
});
```