# How to display all options in Jquery auto complete even if the input does not match any of the strings

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I am using jquery auto complete to populate city names when user starts writing. These cities are from multiple countries and what I want to do now is to populate relevant cities if the user types in country name.

So for example if the user types in `'San'` jquery will populate the auto complete with `['San Diego','Santiago']`. Now if the user types in United States I want the auto complete to be populated with `['New York City', 'Boston', 'Seattle', 'San Diego', etc..]`.

What I can do is to create `HashMap` with country as key and list of cities as value. Then I can just change the source of the auto complete appropriately whenever the input matches a country name.

```
$( "#citySearch" ).autocomplete({source: citySearchList});
```

Now the problem is displaying all options in the source even if `United States` will not trigger `['New York', 'Boston', etc..]` in the normal implementation of autocomplete.

I tried using the trick in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1464868/1303142)

Comment: The results of the `ajax` request are something you'd get from the server, nothing to do with autocomplete or JavaScript at all.  In other words, your server-side code and SQL query is where you'd focus your efforts.

Comment: where do you have the `city` and `county` data stored?

Comment: @JordiCastilla I am getting `cities` through `JSON` and simply using `$( "#citySearch" ).autocomplete({source: citySearchList});` I guess the best solution is to check if the input in the `#citySearch` matches any `country` and populate with relevcant cities.

Comment: how you know relation btw `city-country`?

Comment: I will load them over `JSON` and probably create the javascript equivalent of `hashmap` to store them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the search input contains a name of a country you can get a list of cities from that country and do something like this:

```
$( "#citySearch" ).autocomplete({ source: citySearchList, minLength :0 });
$( "#citySearch" ).autocomplete("search", "");
```

When the input is not a country name in your data, you simply change the source back to the original data.

Setting minLength to 0 and then use the search method to search for "" will display all the data in the autocomplete source array.